# Alias for private docker repository

Tags: docker, repository

Is it possible to define aliases for private docker repository?

I have a repository on the server docker.internal.example.com for internal use, which is not available extern. Now I want to be able to push the images to another repository, docker.distr.example.com, which is available for client installations.

Everything would be OK, if the final images would not depend on intermediate images, referred in FROM, example:

```
FROM docker.internal.example.com:5000/java/jetty-jdk8:latest
```

That image would not be pullable from docker.distr.example.com, because the reference to java/jetty-jdk8 would not be resolved (docker.internal.example.com would not be visible).

Ideally, I'd like to be able to write simply

```
FROM java/jetty-jdk8:latest
```

but I know that for some strange reason it was considered unsecure by docker developers, so something like that would be enough:

```
FROM DOCKER-PRIVATE:5000/java/jetty-jdk8:latest
```

Answer (score 0):

The alias that you are looking for is a DNS entry which you can create locally. You need to figure out the ip address of the private registry.

You can do that by running `host docker.internal.example.com`.

Edit `/etc/hosts` and add an entry like `docker-registry ip-address-of-registry`

Comment: Will docker acknowledge certificate of that server?

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo yes. The dns name will just to resolved to the ip you set in `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: Would this or another change affect the output of `docker images`? I have a lengthy private repository which causes each image entry to wrap onto 2 lines making the command output much less readable. I made an entry with the IP in `/etc/hosts` as recommended, but the output of `docker images` still contains the full, verbose URI

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is relevant to OP question, but I found this question while trying to use a container registry with a different hostname:

- Private registry is reachable on `private.example.com`
- Machine performing image build cannot reach `private.example.com` but can reach `public.somewherelse.com`

It's not possible to use CNAME because TLS certificates for `private.example.com` are managed and cannot be configured.

The solution I came up with:

- Run a reverse proxy on a third machine with access to `private.example.com`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

caddy reverse-proxy \
        --internal-certs \
        --from "public.somewherelse.com" \
        --to https://private.example.com:443 \
        --change-host-header
```

> Note: I use [caddy](https://caddyserver.com/) because it's [very simple to configure](https://caddyserver.com/docs/quick-starts/reverse-proxy) but [haproxy](https://www.haproxy.org/), [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/), [httpd](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/fr/programs/httpd.html), or any other reverse proxy could be used.

From the machine performing image build I can now:

- Pull image :

```bash
docker pull public.somewherelse.com/repository:latest
```

- Push image:

```bash
docker tag public.somewherelse.com/repository:latest public.somewherelse.com/repository:other
docker push public.somewherelse.com/repository:other
```

From machines with access to private registry, pushed images are also available under a different name:

```bash
docker pull private.example.com/repository:other
```

### Pros

- Unlike with entries in `/etc/hosts`, TLS is used to communicate with registry.
- Unlike CNAME there is no need to have a valid certificate for `private.example.com`
- `caddy` in particular is eaasy enough to configure to be used as short-lived sidecar when building images.

### Cons

- Requires an additional process (caddy in my example)
- Increase latency when pulling/pushing images

Answer (score -1):

As I know for now Docker doesn't support aliases.

But you can use one of these possible solutions:

1. Create DNS CNAME entry for your registry domain.

   OR
2. Create alias in /etc/hosts file on machines where you want to use it.

You can read additional details in Google Groups discussion [HERE](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/docker-user/-odvHhqisLg).

Comment: But, you almost surely end with an invalid SSL certificate